# Cardinality of the set $\{f: S\times S\to S \: | \: f \text{ is onto and } f(a,b)=f(b,a)\geq a\ \ \forall (a,b)\in S \times S\}$, with $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I approached it this way. There would be $16$ elements in $S×S$.

Case $1$: $(4,1),(1,4),(4,2),(2,4),(4,3),(3,4)$ and $(4,4)$ will have only $4$ as the choice for their image in $S$

Case $2$: $(3,1),(1,3),(3,2),(2,3)$ and $(3,3)$ can have $3$ and $4$ as the choice for their image in $S$

Case $3$: $(2,1),(1,2)$ and $(2,2)$ can have $2$, $3$ and $4$ as the choice for their image in $S$

and Case $4$: $(1,1)$ can have all of $1$, $2$, $3$ and $4$ as its image but it will have to take the image $1$ to make the function onto.

Similarly any one function in Cases $2$ and $3$ will have to take $3$ and $2$ as their images respectively for function to become onto.

Therefore Total Functions should be= $2$×$2$×$2$×$2$×$3$×$3$= $144$. But the solutions I saw to this problem wrote total functions as $72$. Also I am not able to reach the value of required functions from here. So please explain in elementary terms where I went wrong and how to proceed after this.

PS: The answer to the question is $37$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea looks solid, let's just finish it:

Case $1$ is complete.

Case $2$:  you need to assign values to $(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)$.  A priori we have $2^3=8$ ways to do that, but we may end up having to exclude some depending on how you handle Case $3$

Case $3$:  You need to assign value to $(2,1), (2,2)$ and at least one of these must be $2$.

So:  if, in case $3$, you assign $2$ to one and $3$ to the other ($2$ ways to do that) you are then free to assign values in case $2$.  Thus we get $2\times 2^3=\boxed {16}$ ways to do that.

If, in case $2$ you assign $2$ to one and $4$ to the other, then you only get $2^3-1=7$ ways to handle case $2$ (as you need a $3$), so there are $2\times 7=\boxed {14}$ ways to do that.

If, in case $2$ you assign $2$ to both, then you get $\boxed {7}$

Thus, in total, there are $$16+14+7=\boxed {37}$$

Comment: Ah I understood now, was trying to find total functions and then eliminate the possibilities but think that would have taken a lot of time. Thanks for this clear explanation in easy to understand language!